# Unconnected tables for predefined options in MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-workbench

Is it okay to live some tables not connected to anything?

I have a table with a set of discounts for deals. For each deal, discounts can be summed up, so I don't see the point in connecting the "deals" table and "discounts" table by discount id. I also can't just create INT field for a discount in the "deals" table because discount should be predefined in "discounts" table. How to better organize such database?

Here is the screenshot of the scheme of the DB I have came up with so far.

[image]

Same problem with services. Multiple services can be provided under one deal. Is there a type which can contain multiple strings or numbers?

Comment: *For each deal, discounts can be summed up*, so the relation between `deals` and `discounts` is M:N, and junction table with the structure of `(deals_id, discounts_id)`, where each field is FK to according entity table, must exists. *discount should be predefined in "discounts" table* Impossible - entity instance cannot be self-referenced.

Comment: @Akina Could you elaborate this answer?

Comment: Don't see the point. That's the basics. If you want, you can create self-answer.

Comment: PS. The only chance when non-connected table makes sense seems to be a case when the table is a template table, and its record(s) is used to create a copy into entity table when new entity instance is created.

Comment: @Akina That exactly does M:N relation means? Multiple deals to multiple discounts? In Workbench I can see only 1:n or 1:1 relations.

Comment: `M:N` is really `(entity1) M:1 (junction) 1:N (entity2)`. Three tables and two 1:N relations. *Multiple deals to multiple discounts?* True. If a deal have 5 discounts then junction table have 5 records with its deal_id value and diferent discount_id values. And backward. So none of separate field in junction is unique whereas their pair is unique (and in common is a primary key).

Comment: @Akina In this case, connection fork should be attached to the junction table? Or to deals and discounts? I assume it isn't defined automatically? Or is it? When I have created a foreign key in junction table for deals table, fork attached to the junction table. Is this the right way?

Comment: *When I have created a foreign key injunction table for deals table, fork attached to the junction table. Is this the right way?* Of course.

Comment: @Akina The problem is I also have a fork attached to the deals table from clients table. Which means that one deal can have multiple clients when it should be otherwise. To have a relation a rlation 1 client : many deals I should create the foreign key in clients table for deal_id?

Comment: *Which means that one deal can have multiple clients* ... and one client can have multiple deals? It is M:N again... or one client can have multiple deals whereas one deal is always belonged to one client only? if so you make a mistake with the direction, and client_id is a property of a deal, not backward.

Comment: Short answer:  It is OK to have a table (or set of related tables) that are never `JOINed` to the other tables in a database.  A "list of options" is an example of such.